# Таблица рандомных цветов

Tags: javascript, color, цвета, background-color

делаю проект для колледжа, есть задача:

> Взять за основу сценарий скрипта для таблицы умножения, сделайте таблицу случайных цветов.

Вот сам код таблицы умножения:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<script language="JavaScript">
document.write("<tr><td> </td>");
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
document.write("<td>"+i+" </td>");
document.write("</tr>");
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
document.write("<tr><td>" + i + " </td>");
for (j = 1; j < 10; j++)
{
document.write("<td bgcolor='#00ffa0'>" +
(i*j) + " </td>");
}
document.write("</tr>");
}
</script>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Пробовал сделать так, не работает:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <script language = "JavaScript">
            document.write("<tr><td> </td>");
            for(i =1; i<10; i++)
            {
                color = Math.round(255.0*Math.random());
                r = color.toString(16);
                g = color.toString(16);
                b = color.toString(16);
                color = r+g+b;
                document.write("<td bgcolor=\"${color}\">");
            }
        </script>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Выводит

> ..........

Еще указан пример выбора цвета:

```
color = Math.round(255.0*Math.random());
r = color.toString(16);
```

Исходный цвет указывается как

```
color = r + g + b;
```

Прошу, помогите

Comment: "не работает" --- как много в звуке этом кроется

Comment: хех)) очень....

Comment: это был жирный намёк, на то, что надо написать конкретно что не так. что ожидается и что не получается, что в итоге происходит, хотя должно быть другое

Comment: Смотри, исправил)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляю 100 от балды, можете не добавлять или добавлять другое число, а беру остаток от деления на 256, потому что значения должны быть в диапазоне от 0 до 255:

```html
<table>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    document.write("<tr><td> </td>");

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      document.write("<td>" + i + " </td>");

    document.write("</tr>");

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      document.write("<tr><td>" + i + " </td>");

      for (j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        const r = (Math.random() * (i * j + 100)) % 256;
        const g = (Math.random() * (i * j + 100)) % 256;
        const b = (Math.random() * (i * j + 100)) % 256;

        document.write(`<td bgcolor='rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})'>${(i * j)}</td>`);
      }

      document.write("</tr>");
    }
  </script>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало)

Comment: @David Обращайтесь! Не забудьте отблагодарить галочкой и/или голосом "за" :)

Comment: голос "За" поставить не могу, репутация маленькая :-( . Спасибо тебе)